# Click on link to move cursor to position

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs

Is there any way to jump through a Google document with a link in the sidebar?

I would like to have something like a table of contents in a sidebar. But the document itself should not have a table of contents.

So is there a possibility to jump to a certain position in the document by clicking on this link?

Comment: Yes. A simple look at documentation would have convinced you this is possible. Is there an actual specific question you have? Otherwise this is too broad. https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/document#setCursor(Position)

Comment: Thank you! Sorry, I am not that good in coding. However, I really didn't find that in the documentation, sorry. But I actually have a specific question: How do manage it, to trigger `doc.setCursor(position);` with a click? `onclick=doc.setCursor`doesn't work.

Comment: Perhaps I can specify my question a little bit: I found out, that I can get the position of a heading with `var position = doc.newPosition(p.asParagraph(), 0);`. But can I put that position in a link? So that I can jump to that point, when I click on it? It seems to me, that position is not a variable that is printable in HTML code.

Comment: Why do you need to put that position in a link? Don't you instead need to *scroll to* that position *after* clicking a link?

Comment: That was my approach to that task. Yes: The user should click on that link and then the cursor should move to the position. So I thought it would be necessary to have this position. Do you have another idea, how to move through the document?

Comment: You don't need to incorporate the position into the link. The link needs to result in scrolling to the position. Store link <-> position reference relationship. Use that relationship when a link is clicked.

Comment: Okay. That‘s a gooh idea. I will work on that, thanks!

Comment: I think, I am closer to a solution. But I encountered another problem. I do put every heading in a new range: `rangeBuilder = doc.newRange().addElement(paragraphs[i]);`and then retrieve its id for the link `var id = doc.addNamedRange(name, rangeBuilder.build()).getId();` That does work so far. Then I try to set its Position when the link is clicked: `var rangeElement = doc.getNamedRangeById(id).getRange().getRangeElements()[0];`and `var position = doc.newPosition(rangeElement.getElement(), rangeElement.getStartOffset());`But StartOffset is always -1. Why?

Comment: I tried it several times now, but StartOffset is alway -1. Even when I try to extract the StartOffset just after buidling the range. I also tested, that it is the right range with `rangeElement.getElement().asText().getText();` So, the range is the right one. But Offset always is -1. I just do not understand why.

Answer (score 0):

There is a Chrome Add-on for Google Docs that seems to do exactly what you want.

[Chrome Table of Contents Add-on](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/table-of-contents/ickpeaanccmmabadbfiknbobkmkdnnaj?utm_source=permalink)

I usually use it with the built-in ToC, but if you don't have one of those it still seems to work. Relies upon the styles (Heading 1, etc.) to work though.

Comment: Thank you! I am using that add-on and would like to build nearly the same, but slightly modified.

Comment: I think you could use [bookmarks](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/bookmark)

Comment: The thing is, that script should work for every document with headings, like the "Table of Contents" App-on does. I already made it, to list the headings in the sidebar. But what doesn't work is to jump to the position of the heading, when I click on it. The "Table of contents" add-on seems to work with NamedRanges. All links contain `onclick="setCursorAtNamedRange('i179ny5to78x');`- but I do not know, what this function does exactly.